# How can i disable button from submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid inside a form, in the grid i have Edit Button to display Edit Popup window, but when i click on it submits the form to a controller, Is there anyway to prevent from submitting the form?

`<button class="btn btn-link" onkeydown="editGridRow(&quot;AddressGrid&quot;, this)" onclick="editGridRow(&quot;AddressGrid&quot;, this)">Edit</button>`

I also have another button to save the changes made, i only want to submit the form when Save button below clicked

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp;Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so when you click on submit button , a **default** action happens that is to submit the form

so to **prevent** that **default** action from happening you use a function called `preventDefault`

read a simple solution here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-set-up-preventdefault-on-form-submit/245580

read about preventDefault here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: please check the `selector` in your querySelector. try to see in isolation if it is even selecting your button

Comment: so this part `document.querySelector(".btn btn-success")` is what is supposed to select the button right ?  see what this part evaluates to

Comment: ".btn btn-success" is incorrect
if you wish to select an element with className of "btn-success" inside of a parent element with className of "btn"
try ".btn .btn-success".
"btn-success" without dot does not refer to anything so it's null

Comment: @ShawnVn .. i just wanted him to figure it out himself , he is new to language

Comment: Thank you @ShawnVn!! Thank you for the Help!